# Display the number of comments of each post related to the same post in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, blogs

Hello friends I am building a blog and I have encountered a problem. My problem is that when I want to display the number of comments for each post, on the main page of the blog number of comments displays all posts that have comments, but the number of comments for each post is the same. In the event that post 2 has 3 comments and the other has 1 comment.

You can see in this picture.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppWIy.jpg)

This is Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
body = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=[self.created_date.year,
                                        self.created_date.strftime('%m'),
                                        self.created_date.strftime('%d'),
                                        self.slug])

def active_comment(self):
    return self.comments.filter(active=True)
```

This is Comment model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
email = models.EmailField()
comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} by {}".format(self.comment, self.name)
```

This is my views.py

```
def post_list(request):
posts = models.Post.objects.filter(status='published')
paginator = Paginator(posts, 4)
page_number = request.GET.get('page')
page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
comment_count = models.Comment.objects.filter(active=True).count()
context = {
    'page_obj': page_obj,
    'comment_count': comment_count,
}
# print(posts)
return render(request, "post_list.html", context=context)
```

And this too post_list.html

```
        <article class="col-12 col-md-6 tm-post">
        <hr class="tm-hr-primary">

        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"
           class="effect-lily tm-post-link tm-pt-60">
            <div class="tm-post-link-inner">
                <img src="/{{ post.image }}/" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>

            <h2 class="tm-pt-30 tm-color-primary tm-post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        </a>

        <p class="tm-pt-30">
            {{ post.body|slice:254 }}
        </p>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between tm-pt-45">
            <span class="tm-color-primary">Travel . Events</span>
            <span class="tm-color-primary">{{ post.created_date.year }}/{{ post.created_date.month }}/{{ post.created_date.day }}</span>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <span>
                    {% for comment in post.active_comment|slice:"1" %}
                        {{ comment_count }}<span> Comment</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </span>
            <span>{{ post.author|capfirst }}</span>
        </div>
    </article>
```

please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the related_name to be “comments” inside the comment model.
That is where the Fielderror is coming from
Change the  “comment_set” inside the query to “comments” and let’s see

Answer (score 2):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) with:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

# …

posts = Post.objects.annotate(number_of_comments=Count('comment', filter=Q(comment__active=True)))
```

The `Post` objects that arise from this `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.number_of_comments`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if possible, explain how to use it. I mean, where should I use this, like in views.py or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

based on @willem post you need to edit your template accordingly too:

```
posts = Post.objects.annotate(number_of_comments=Count('comment', filter=Q(comment_set__active=True)))
```

and in the template

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
   <span>{{post.number_of_comments}}</span>
   <span>{{ post.author|capfirst }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I add posts = Post.objects.annotate(number_of_comments=Count('comment_set', filter=Q(comment_set__active=True))) to views.py in post_list function, I get this error

FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'comment_set' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, body, comment, created_date, id, image, slug, status, title

Comment: can you post also the Post entity please?

Comment: Yes, dear friend, post model entities have been placed